# Create a save Session in Python

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine

Is it secure to use a session variable, that is created like this:

```
base64.b64encode(os.urandom(256))
```

`urandom` is said to deliver a good randomness. `base64` then only encodes this string. Is this argumentation correct and the method therefore secure?

---

@Qiau pointed out, `os.urandom` depends on the OS-implementation. In my case (the script runs on `Google App Engine`) this seams to be secure to use [(see Google Groups post)](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1055).

Comment: save or safe ? if safe, please explain your definition of safe...

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.

Comment: safe of course, thanks for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is correct. base64 only encodes the string.

From documentation:

> urandom(...)
>
> ```
>    urandom(n) -> str
>
>    Return n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.
> ```
>
> b64encode(s, altchars=None)
>
> ```
>    Encode a string using Base64.
> ```

It should be unpredictable enough for cryptographic applications according to [documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

> This function returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source. The returned data should be unpredictable enough for cryptographic applications, though its exact quality depends on the OS implementation. On a UNIX-like system this will query /dev/urandom, and on Windows it will use CryptGenRandom(). If a randomness source is not found, NotImplementedError will be raised.